# Using data binding on value which is a FrameworkElement

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, frameworkelement

One of my data sources produces a collection of values which are typed to the following interface

```
public interface IData
{
    string Name { get; }
    FrameworkElement VisualElement { get; }
}
```

I'd like to use data binding in WPF to display a collection of `IData` instances in a `TabControl` where the `Name` value becomes the header of the tab and the `VisualElement` value is displayed as the content of the corresponding tab.

Binding the header is straight forward.  I'm stuck though on how to define a template which allows me to display the `VisualElement` value.  I've tried a number of solutions with little success.  My best attempt is as follows.

```
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                How do I display VisualElement here?
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

I'm still very new to WPF so I could be missing the obvious here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ContentPresenter`s were made for this. The content template becomes:

```
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding VisualElement}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

I tested it with a `TextBlock` and a `TextBox`.

Comment: Worked like a champ!  Thanks!